# Xquery - return an aggregation as a new attribute

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I want to be able to get a certain kind of aggregation and put that as a new attribute in what I return using xquery.

Currently I have code like this:

```
for $x in //donors
where $x/donor[count(donations) > 5] 
return <bigDonors>
            <donor> 
                {$x/@donor_id}
                {count($x/donor/donations)}
                <name>{$x/donor/firstname}</name>
            </donor>
       </bigDonors>
```

I want to get back something like:

```
<bigDonors>
    <donor donor_id='xx123' numberDonations='5'> 
        <name>Bobbert Bobbily</name>
    </donor>
.
.
.
</bigDonors>
```

I don't know how to get the number of donations as an attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have been a bit easier if we knew the source format we're working with so I had to make a few assumptions and used this test XML snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<donors>
  <donor donor_id="tst01">
    <firstname>Alice</firstname>
    <donation value="2000"/>
    <donation value="3000"/>
    <donation value="4000"/>
  </donor>
  <donor donor_id="tst02">
    <firstname>Bob</firstname>
    <donation value="2000"/>
  </donor>
</donors>
```

I then used the following query:

```
for $donor in //donors/donor
where $donor[count(donation) > 2] 
return <bigDonors>
         <donor donor_id="{$donor/@donor_id}" donations="{count($donor/donation)}"> 
           <name>{$donor/firstname/text()}</name>
         </donor>
       </bigDonors>
```

To get this result:

```
<bigDonors>
  <donor donor_id="tst01" donations="3">
    <name>Alice</name>
  </donor>
</bigDonors>
```

Basically the solution to your issue was to directly write the attributes you want into the result tag and get their contents using XPath expressions inside the attributes, wrapped in {}.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that but didn't put the double quotes in, so that's why it didn't work. . heh

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be using [computed attribute constructor](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#doc-xquery-CompAttrConstructor) like so :

```
for $x in //donors
where $x/donor[count(donations) > 5] 
return <bigDonors>
            <donor> 
                {attribute donor_id{$donor/@donor_id}}
                {attribute donations{count($donor/donation)}}
                <name>{$x/donor/firstname}</name>
            </donor>
       </bigDonors>
```

Computed attribute constructor is useful especially when we need to create attribute with dynamic (computed) name.